# GitHub Action - Failed to restart XXX.service: Interactive authentication required

Tags: linux, shell, github, ssh, systemctl

I'm trying to auto-deploy changes in `Django` project using `GitHub Actions`. There is a problem with restarting services. It says:

```
Failed to restart gunicorn/nginx.service: Interactive authentication required.
```

How can I make it work?

This is the `deploy.yml`

```
name: deploying changes
on:
  push:
    branches: [staging]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: deploying changes
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: xxx.xx.xx.xxx
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
          script: |
            cd proj/
            sh deploy.sh
```

**deploy.sh**

```
# Cd into the required directory
cd proj/

# Pull the changes
git pull


python manage.py migrate

# Collectstatic
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# Restart gunicorn and reload nginx
service gunicorn restart
service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding `sudo` before the service:

```
sudo service gunicorn restart
# OR sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm.service
```